# Method MyClass::__get() must take exactly 1 argument

Tags: object, php

Im getting error, when im trying to create new instance of my class.

```
class MyClass
{    
    public $link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Connect();
    }

    private function Connect()
    {
        $db_host = DB_HOST; // defined in included file
        $db_name = DB_NAME; // defined in included file

        $this->link = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=UTF-8", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

        $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,FALSE);

    }

    // other methods here
    // there is no custom __get() method
}
```

Im trying to create new instance and use one of methods:

```
include "inc/myclass.php";
$db = new MyClass();
$db->InsertPost("2012-01-01 10:00", "Test content", "Test title");
```

Im getting error:

> Method MyClass::__get() must take exactly 1 argument

I tried to add accessor without any parameter:

```
public function __get() 
{
    return $this;
}
```

But im still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to override default accessor (get) like this:

```
public function __get($name) 
{
    return $this;
}
```

I don't understand why i need `$name` there, but it works perfect.